# Adding a delay pr timer to an Angular .get() to test latency

Tags: angularjs, timer

I am trying to add a delay to an Angular .get() request so I can simulate latency or a slow network. I want to test how timer animations are displayed etc.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Here is a sample of my .get()

```
 $scope.loading = true;


    // get all the portfolios and the products
    //http.get('scripts/json/sample-products.json')
    $http.get('http://www.website.com/Pricing/GetProductCatalogue')
        .then(function (allProducts) {
            $scope.listOfProducts = allProducts.data.Connectivity;
        })
        .finally(function() {
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
```

The scope loading would be the div I use to contain my loading animations and messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a timeout (with `$timeout` or `window.setTimeout`) in the succes function, like this:

```
$scope.loading = true;


    // get all the portfolios and the products
    //http.get('scripts/json/sample-products.json')
    $http.get('http://www.website.com/Pricing/GetProductCatalogue')
        .then(function (allProducts) {
            $timeout(function(){
                $scope.listOfProducts = allProducts.data.Connectivity;
            },10000)

        })
        .finally(function() {
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

```
$scope.loading = true;

var getFunc = function(){
    $http.get('http://www.website.com/Pricing/GetProductCatalogue')
    .then(function (allProducts) {
        $scope.listOfProducts = allProducts.data.Connectivity;
    })
    .finally(function() {
        $scope.loading = false;
    });
}

$timeout(getFunc, 1000);
```

And do not forget to inject $timeout into your controller

Comment: with this timeout you are not simulating the delay in the response, but you are delaying the execution of the call...